# how to get Master report variable value into subreport variables in Jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

how to get or assign  the Master report variable value into subreport variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iReport in your subreport properties look for the **Parameters** property and click the button on the right of the text box.

This will open an input box.

Click the **Add** button in this box and add the parameters you require.